# How to add a trailing navigationbaritem conditionally to a SwiftUI View which will be presented in a NavigationView?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uibarbuttonitem, ios-navigationview

To add navigationBarItem to a SwiftUI View we can use code similar to this:

```
NavigationView {
    Text("SwiftUI")
        .navigationBarTitle("Welcome")
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Help") {
                    print("Help tapped!")
           }
        )
    }
```

How can this be done conditionally. Say if an array is empty show the "Help" bar button else do not show the bar button.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can conditionally return the button as the view or nil if the array is empty

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var arr = ["String"] // also test [String]()

    var body: some View {

     NavigationView {
        Text("SwiftUI")
            .navigationBarTitle("Welcome")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: !arr.isEmpty ? Button("Help") {
                        print("Help tapped!")
                } : nil
            )
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hmm... it works, but it is strange, 'cause by interface contract `nil` should not be accepted. Could not be it side-effect of...?

Comment: @Asperi exactly the reason I asked this question. Seemed to me that the view to return should be non optional. Is there a possible explaination how this answer works?

Comment: IMO more correctly to use `EmptyView()` instead of `nil`.